# What do functions with the same name do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ruby and can't for the life of it figure out what this does:

```
def topic_list
  topics.map(&:name).join(",")
end

def topic_list=(names)
  if names.present?
    topics = names.split(",")
    self.topics = topics.map do |n|
      unless topic = Topic.find_by(slug: n)
        topic = Topic.create!(name: n)
      end
      topic
    end
  end
end
```

Why would two functions have the same name? Does the first function call the second one?

Comment: Look closely: they *don't* have the same name. One is named `topic_list`, the other is named `topic_list=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`topic_list` is a *getter* and `topic_list=` is a *setter* method. No they are not the same methods.

This question [Trying to learn / understand Ruby setter and getter methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737421/trying-to-learn-understand-ruby-setter-and-getter-methods) will be helpful as a basic food for this concept. So Read it.

The line `self.topics = topics.map...` in the method `topic_list=`, and `topics.map(&:name).join(",")` line in the method `topic_list` smells there is one getter called `topics` and setter `topics=`. I am sure(If you tell this code works altough) about this by looking at your code.

Comment: @Hopstream No it is not like that. OP took the part of the code, to understand the topic.

Comment: How does the getter get the `:name` if it doesn't have any arguments? In this: `topics.map(&:name).join(",")`

Comment: @user3188544 I am sure as `self.topics=` is used in the method `topic_list=`. So there obviously exist an instance variable `@topics` and there must be exist getter `topics` and setter `topics=`.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify [Arup Rakshit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21425608/73673) a little more:

Ruby allows having some "weird" characters in its methods, that you would normally not see in other languages. The most notably ones are `?`, `!` and `=`.

So, you can define the methods:

```
def answered?()
  not @answer.nil?
end

def answer!()
  @answer = Answer.new
end

def answer()
  @answer
end

def answer=(answer)
  @answer = answer
end
```

For someone coming from, say, PHP, this looks strange. But really they are all different methods! I have added brackets everywhere, to clarify my point, but in Ruby, you can leave them off, so when a method does not take arguments,people generally leave them off.

```
def answer()
end
def answer
end
```

Are the same.

The last two, the `answer()` and `answer=()`, are often refered to as getters and setters. The first is often used to test something binary, like `has_question?` or `valid?`. The second is referred to as a *bang* method, `answer!`, more often used in methods that modify itself, like `some_array.merge!(other_array)`, which modifies `some_array`.