# How to pull information from associated model (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ransack

I'm running a search using the Ransack gem.

Controller code (for ItemsController)

```
@q = Item.search(params[:q])
@search_results = @q.result
```

After running the search, `@search_results` contains multiple `Items` (Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, …). Where each Item is a hash:

```
Item = { "id" => "12", "name" => "shovel", "user_id" => "2", "type" => "A" }
```

In this case, for each Item hash, I want to add an additional key-value pair that translates the `user_id` into the name that is associated with that instance of the `User` model (i.e., `User has_many :Items` and `Item belongs_to :Users`)

I tried in the same controller code section

```
@search_results.each do |item|
    item[:user_name] = User.find_by_id(item.user_id).name
end
```

But I get an error that I can't write to item. I suspect Ransack has something to do with it though, because if I just print `@search_results`, instead of getting the actual Item data, I get `#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Item:0x000001025e6c78>`

Help greatly appreciated!

Btw, in case there's even an easier way, the reason I want to add another key/value pair with the user_name is because the ultimate output is a JSON that is being picked up by another part of the codebase, and we don't want to run two separate database queries.

Comment: Well as for appending to hashes use:
`item[:user_name] << User.find_by_id(item.user_id).name` in the each do block, or `item.merge!(user_name:  User.find_by_id(item.user_id).name
)`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you're receiving a ruby object back, which I take means you can create a set of attributes for in the model. Why don't you try using a [getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737421/trying-to-learn-understand-ruby-setter-and-getter-methods) in your `item` model to set for you:

```
#app/models/item.rb
Class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user #-> needs to be singular
    attr_accessor :user_name

    def user_name
       self.user.name
    end
end
```

This means that instead of having to append a `user_name` attribute from your controller, every `Item` object will automatically have the `user_name` attribute anyway

A refactor of this would also be to use the [`delegate` method](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) inside your `Item` model:

```
Class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true #-> allows you to call @item.user_name
end
```

Comment: That's fine in the sense that I can get the data, but if I call the Item as an object, `user_name` is still missing from the hash (true in both approaches).