# In ruby on rails 4, how do I set an attribute in the forms_for helper that is not associated with a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I want to be able to access `:to_whom` text value via `params[:to_whom]` in the controller. To_whom does not exist in a model.

**I get the sensible error:
'undefined method `to_whom' for Conversation'**

How can I add an arbitrary attribute to pass back to the controller in rails?

Also, in my view I did `Message.new` and `Conversation.new` which is incredibly ugly. I initially set `@conversation = Conversation.new` in the controller, however I found I had to recreate those variables in the second controller method anyways, which makes sense (after I hit the submit button). Thus instead of setting `@message`, `@conversation` in the `new` method, I removed all the lines from `new` and did the `.new` syntax in the view. Is there a more elegant way of writing this code so it isn't so hacky feeling?

CONTROLLER:

```
 class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
   attr_accessor :conversation, :user, :to_whom

   # this is the method that generates the below view
   def new
   end

   def create
      ...
   end
 end
```

VIEW:

```
<%= form_for([current_user, Conversation.new]) do |c| %>
  <%= c.label :to_whom %>
  <%= c.text_field :to_whom %>

  <%= c.label :subject %>
  <%= c.text_field :subject %>   
  <%= form_for(Message.new) do |m| %>
  <%= m.label :message %>
  <%= m.text_field :text %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= submit_tag "send" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Virtual Attributes**

Your [`attr_accessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) belongs in your model (not your controller). Currently, you have it stored in your `controller`, which will do nothing at the model-level:

```
#app/models/conversation.rb
Class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :conversation, :user, :to_whom
end

#app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb
    # remove attr_accessor
```

You have to remember that since Ruby is object-orientated, all the `data` objects you get are from the `model`. This means if you call `@conversation = Conversation.new`, the `attributes` of that model are actually created in the `conversation` model

Normally, the model will set the attributes in accordance with your database columns. If you don't have a database column present, you need to create the relevant [`getter` / `setter` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737421/trying-to-learn-understand-ruby-setter-and-getter-methods) using the `attr_accessor` module

Answer (score 2):

`m.text_field :to_whom` is just a helper to build an html input tag.  You could write your own in raw html, filling in the blanks with erb tags, or you could use other helpers, such as `text_field_tag`:

```
text_field_tag "to_whom", params[:to_whom]
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't see this in the docs :D I will approve your answer. You answered really quick so StackOverFlow isn't letting me do it yet.

Comment: Did it work? I thought the issue would be with your declaration of `attr_accessor`

Comment: Actually that's a good point - i missed the attr_accessor.  The attr_accessor doesn't work because you've defined it in the controller.  It needs to be in the Conversation model.

Comment: You should give @RichPeck the right answer, mine is more like a work around for you not using attr_accessor properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use fields_for helper, It should be something like below,

```
= c.fields_for :message do
```