# Custom fields in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Trying to create a profile form in which a user can add information about their hobbies to their user profile. But I get the following error when trying to do so.

```
    NoMethodError in Users#edit_profile

    undefined method `hobbies' for #<User:0x007ff1a8a1f198>
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be, or a potential solution? I'm new to rails but I was under the impression that 'text_field' was a safe bet to make any custom input work. Would installing the strong parameters gem help this out at all?

edit_profile.html.erb

```
<h2>Tell us about yourself</h2>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>

    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

    <%= f.label :hobbies %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :hobbies %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    def create
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.update!(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    end

    def destroy
    end

    def edit_profile
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :hobbies)
    end

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :hobbies

  #validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  #validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

end
```

Comment: Do you have a hobbies column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention it, but I will assume you're running Rails 4.x.

Rails 4.x introduced [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), so in your controller you need to add a private method to set the allowed parameters and remove the `attr_accessible` from your model.

So in you case it will be:

```
 def user_params
    params.require(:first_name, :last_name).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :hobbies)
  end
```

If you still have trouble to understand the concept, or came from a previous Rails version, take a look at [this blog post](http://easyactiverecord.com/blog/2014/04/01/rails4-strong-parameters-and-the-attr-accessible-macro/).

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know what the problem could be, or a potential solution?

Sure - the problem is you don't have a `hobbies` attribute in your `User` model :)

Since you're new, I'll explain a bit about Rails after I answer the question. However, let me explain the value of creating the right attributes:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :hobbies
end
```

This is what you'll need to create a single *attribute* for your `User` model. The [`attr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) directive is a Ruby method which sets a `getter` and `setter` in your `User` model

This will give Rails the ability to populate the `hobbies` attribute of your `Model`. However, the data will not be persistent, as it will only be set on a *per-instance* basis in the model, meaning it will be lost when you refresh the page etc

Using the code above *should* get your form working, regardless of whether you're using Rails 3 or 4.

---

**Models**

Rails is famously an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework - which means it has 3 core components - `models` (builds data from the database), `controllers` (configure data for the view) & `views` (displays the data from the controller & model).

When you load a Rails application, you're sending a *request*, which will be *routes* to a particular controller action. This will then call data from your database, allowing you to manipulate it in your view.

`Models`, therefore have to be populated from your database. They do this by taking the various *attributes* you have in your datatables, and creating a series of [`getters and setters`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737421/trying-to-learn-understand-ruby-setter-and-getter-methods) for them. These give you the ability to access the data within the attributes, or set new ones.

Your error occurs because you don't have the relevant attribute set in your datatable. You'll need to [create a migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) to add the `hobbies` attribute to your `User` model:

```
> $ rails g migration AddHobbiesToUser hobbies:string
> $ rake db:migrate
```

The migration should create something like:

```
class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :hobbies, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer Rich. When you say that the data will not be persistent, does this mean that it will not be stored in the database when the form is submitted?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Data persistence is like having it stored on your hard drive - it's there forever if you want it

Comment: To answer your earlier question, i'm using rails 4.1, is there any way make the data persistent? whats your take on using strong_parameters?