# Getting error: unknown attribute: poster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So everything was working earlier. I cut a branch and made some changes that I didn't think would affect this poster attribute but I got this error. I switched to master and did not merge anything, and this was working before I cut the branch I mention above. And I got this error also.

I'm not sure what happened, maybe I twitched and put in a keystroke somewhere but I can't see it.

It says the error is in my restaurants controller. I'm using the poster attribute in my show.index.html.

show.index.html:

```
<% @restaurant.reviews.reverse.each do |review| %>
posted by: <%= review.poster %><br />
written: <%= time_ago_in_words(review.created_at) %> ago<br />
Review:<br />
<%= review.article %><br /><br />
<% end %>
```

The method for review in my restaurants_controller.rb:

```
def review
  @restaurant.reviews << Review.create!(review_params) ## <= this is the offending piece of code
  redirect_to :action => "show", :id => params[:id]
end
```

The method for review_params in restaurants_controller.rb:

```
def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:poster, :article)
end
```

I'm not sure what changed to make me get unknown attribute but if someone could help I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: That `review` method in the restaurants controller is particularly offensive. **1)** Where is `@restaurant` being assigned? **2)** Where is the review method being called from? **3)** Please post the full error message.

Comment: whats your git status

Comment: @MichalSzyndel The only thing in git status is about solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely down to two potential issues:

> 1. Your `poster` attribute is conflicting with your `poster` association
> 2. You don't have a `poster` attribute

Let me explain:

---

**Association**

Upon first seeing your code, I would have presumed your `poster` "attribute" would have, in fact, been an [ActiveRecord association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). This means that if you call the *poster* method, it will access the data from the associated model:

```
#app/models/review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | poster_id | title | body | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :poster, class_name: "User"
   delegate :name, to: :poster, prefix: true #-> poster_name
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :reviews
end
```

This association will give you the ability to call the the following (considering your database is set up correctly):

```
<% @restaurant.reviews.reverse.each do |review| %>
    <%= review.poster_name %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Attribute**

In regards to your attribute issue - the bottom line is whether you have a column called `poster` in your `Review` model / table.

> To give you a more detailed explanation, you must remember that Rails
>   is an [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) framework (by virtue of being built on Ruby), which means that every time you
>   perform any functionality with it, it will "build" objects for you. We
>   see these objects as our `Models`, but in reality, they are just Ruby
>   classes with "attributes" appended to them, depending on the database.

You can see this most evidently with [this documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes%3D) - every time you initialize a Rails / Ruby class, it's actually "building" an object with a series of [instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737421/trying-to-learn-understand-ruby-setter-and-getter-methods), which we come to know as its *attributes*:

[image]

This means that if you're receiving an "unknown attribute" error, it means that your `Model` cannot build the attributes you desire. The base definition for this is that **you don't have the correct column in your database**, but moreover, you may be able to resolve with a simple fix (hack).

I would **strongly recommend creating a migration to populate a *poster* column** in your db. However, to see if this is the problem or not, you may wish to use [`attr_accessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible) to create a "virtual attribute":

```
#app/models/review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :poster #-> to test whether this will resolve the issue
end
```

Comment: Tell me the error. Means another part of your code has a problem

Comment: `attr_accessor :poster` did work. I think this is going to be me not understanding git and db. 

I was going to not let people enter the poster on a review and tie the user authentication from devise to the review. So I added a migration and in the migration file: `remove_column :reviews, :poster`. Then db:migrate.

Since I didn't merge that branch I thought I would still have the poster column in the database. But I don't do I?

I need to get that back. I did run `rake db:migrate` my test branch thinking that would recreate but it didn't fix it. So not sure how to get poster back.

Comment: `undefined method `poster' for #<Review:0x007fe5eca23300>`

For this line:
`posted by: <%= review.poster %><br />`

Comment: Did you change the models to those I outlined?

Comment: Running the migration and adding poster column back in worked.