# Ruby Class setter

Tags: ruby, class, setter

I have difficulties understanding the setter and how to apply the value in use.

In the below example,

```
  def time_string=(seconds)
    @time_string = calculator(seconds)
  end
```

How can I get the seconds' value from setter?

Thanks a lot

```
class Timer
  def seconds
    @seconds = 0
  end

  def time_string
    @time_string
  end

  def seconds=(t)
    @seconds = t
  end

  def time_string=(seconds)
    @time_string = calculator(seconds)
  end

  def calculator(x)
    array = []
    sec = (x % 60).to_s
    min = ((x / 60 ) % 60).to_s
    hour = (x / 3600).to_s
    temp = [hour, min, sec]
    temp.map {|i| i.length < 2 ? array.push("0#{i}") : array.push("#{i}") }
    array.join(":")
 end

end
```

Comment: it looks like your setting seconds to 0; is this intentional? Why not just use attr_accessor? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby  You will always be returning 0 in your sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get what you're trying to accomplish. First, all that calculate code...why? Why not use the methods in the `Time` class? Second, **there are not such thing as setters** in Ruby. Everything in Ruby is a **method**. So technically, what you call a setter is a *method that acts like a setter.* In your code, both methods  `seconds=` and `seconds` act as a setter (the first sets `@seconds` to the return value of the `calculator` call, and the second method sets `@seconds` to 0).

You can't get the seconds value from a setter method, the purpose of a setter method is, after all, to SET something. If you want to get something, use a getter method. And it's pretty simple to create a getter method, just change your `seconds` method to this:

```
def seconds
     @seconds # we GET the value of @seconds now, we don't set it to 0
end
```

Ruby can create this method automatically in the background for you with just one line added inside your class, and that line is `attr_reader :seconds`. Each time you see this in some Ruby code, assume that what Ruby does in the background is generate something similar to the `seconds` method above. In the same fashion, if you want Ruby to also automatically generate a setter method code like this:

```
def seconds=(t)
    @seconds = t
end
```

then use `attr_writer :seconds`. These attr_reader and attr_writer methods exist because making setter and getter methods is so common that this shortens your program significantly, especially if you have, say, 10 instance variables (you have `@seconds` and `@time_string` now , but you could also have instance variables for minutes, hours, days, etc. that would be a lot of methods for getting/setting the instance variables!). In the same fashion, you could also create a getter method automatically for `@time_string` as well:

```
def time_string
    @time_string
end
```

But NOT a setter method because your set logic for `@time_string` is kinda different than the method Ruby would create (attr_reader and attr_writer create simple getter/setter methods), if you type `attr_writer :time_string`, then Ruby would create this method in the background:

```
def time_string=(some_value)
  @time_string = some_value
end
```

which is not what you want. You can simplify your code a lot, here's my version:

```
class Timer
  attr_reader :seconds, :time_string
  attr_writer :seconds

  def time_string=(seconds)
    @time_string = calculator(seconds)
  end

  def calculator(x)
    Time.at(x).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end

end

a = Timer.new
a.seconds = 30
p a.seconds #=> 30
a.time_string = 50
p a.time_string #=> "00:00:50"
```

You could also further simplify this code by using `attr_accessor` for seconds, for that I recommend [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371458/1085998) which explains more about these shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally got enough reputation to vote you back, =)

Comment: Thank you :) If you found my answer useful, feel free to accept it by clicking on the checkbox which should be below the answer points on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why do you want to return value from setters. setters are used to applying initial values to the class variables. you can use accessors to retrieve the value of your instance variables.

If you have problems understanding setters and accessors I would suggest reading the following link :
[Trying to learn / understand Ruby setter and getter methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737421/trying-to-learn-understand-ruby-setter-and-getter-methods)