# Explanation of the @ variables inside Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've worked through a few Rails applications which are using @ attribute variables (which are already attr_accessible) in the models. I was having a tough time getting information on this but from what I gather `name` and `@name` are the same thing in a model but im probably incorrect on this.

How do these @ variables work and why would one ever use the @ symbol variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to the current answers, [`@instance_variables`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable) are from [**object oriented programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)...

> In `object-oriented programming` with classes, an `instance variable` is a variable defined in a class (i.e. a member variable), for which **each instantiated object** of the class has a separate copy, or *instance*.

---

## OOP

"Normal" programming has variables as pieces of data -- `strings`, `integers` etc. These are independent & can only interact as part of other functions, depending on their scope.

Object Oriented programming (OOP) can treat variables as pieces of **editable** data (known as `classes`). These *classes* can be *invoked*, *edited* and most importantly *interacted*...

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  #-> class
end

def new
   @product = Product.new #-> creating a new instance of the class
end
```

Ruby/Rails is object oriented; it works by giving you a series of *objects* to load & interact with. The most notable example is with [game programming](http://superprofundo.com/2010/12/09/object-oriented-programming-in-a-nutshell/):

[image]

The way object orienting works is to invoke/initialize an *instance* of a class (in our case `Product`), allowing you to manipulate it.

Class *instances* hold the object in memory, allowing you to perform actions on the class itself. To do this, you'd store the *instance* of the class in a variable, allowing you to interact with the variable itself:

```
@product = Product.new
@product.save
```

--

*Instance* variables are only valid within the **context of the `class`**:

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product = Product.new #-> @product only available within ProductsController
  end
end
```

The controllers in Rails are `classes`, invoked through a rack request:

```
Request > Rack > Routes > ProductsController.new(request).show > Response
```

If you want your `@instance_variable` available in all methods of the class, it has to be at `instance` level...

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product = Product.new
    product_save
  end

  private

  def product_save
    @product.save #-> @product available in instance of ProductsController class
  end
end
```

---

The most common use for `@instance_variables` are to store / manipulate instance-centric data. A good example (for our `Product` example) could be the `stock` level:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def stock
     @qty / @orders
  end
end
```

Because you can use [`getter/setter` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737421/trying-to-learn-understand-ruby-setter-and-getter-methods) within Ruby, you can define the instance values of a class, accessing them through other instance data:

```
@product = Product.find x
@product.stock #-> outputs stock value for that product
```

Answer (score 3):

"@" in front of the name signifies that it is an instance variable of the model class, which is different than a simple ruby variable name. Instance (@) variables can be used in the front-end (views).

For example, you can instantiate a variable @book which is a specific instance of the Book class (which is the model). So when you use @book, you are referring to that specific book you created, rather than the overall class.

There is also a difference in the methods you can call on instance versus class variables.

---

Comment: It is quite strange to me. If creating an instance variable(starting with `@`) from model and access it from view layer. To be honest, it is a horrible design and hard to manage with. You have to be a great reason to create an instance variable from model. Could you show some example? Why not from controller?

Answer (score 2):

Variables beginning with @ are *instance variables*, in short they allow other methods of the same class to use them. For example,

```
class Something
  def a_method(name)
    @i_variable = name
    normal_variable = "hey"
  end

  def another_method
    @i_variable.reverse #can be seen here and used
    normal_variable  #cannot be seen here and cannot be used, throws an error
  end
end
```

In Rails, I believe instance variables are important because they are visible across the Model, View, Controller parts of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Variables that start with `@` are instance variables.  This means that belong to an instance of a class.  So if I had the following class:

```
class Dog 
    def initialize(name, breed)
        @name = name
        @breed = breed
    end 
end
```

Everytime I create a `Dog`, I need to give it a name and a breed.

```
fido = Dog.new("Fido", "Dalmation")
```

Because I created instance variables from the `name` and `breed` I can get this information from `fido`.

```
fido.name => "Fido"

fido.breed => "Dalmation"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
def foo
  thing = "value"
end

foo
puts thing
```

You will get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `thing' for main:Object
```

If you do this:

```
def foo
  @thing = "value"
end

foo
puts @thing
```

You will get "value"

You see, @variables are visible to the whole class you are operating on, in this case the model.

The @variables are also used a lot in controllers, like this:

```
def hello
  @current_user_name = User.find(params[:user_id]).name
end
# and in the view:
Hello, <%= @current_user_name %>
```

Because if you didn't use @, you would have made a local variable and that is not accessible by the view.

Answer (score 0):

A var with @ is an instance private variable. A var without @ is a local method variable.

A variable with @ can be accessed on an object's level if the object has a method returning a value of or setting a value to it being attr_accessor, attr_reader or def.